# Error: Command failed: unoconv node js

Tags: node.js

I want to convert `pptx` file to `pdf` format. For this, I have used `office-converter` npm package so when I run command to convert file from `pptx` to `pdf I am getting below error:

> Error:
>
> Command failed: unoconv -f pdf 'unoconv' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you install unoconv and add it to the path?

Comment: Yes i have installed unoconv. where i have to add path?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-converter) of `office-converter` clearly says that the package requires `unoconv` to be installed. You should be able to get it with `apt-get`/`apt` or some other package manger but I'm not sure, you should try for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For converting `pptx` to `pdf`, instead of `office-converter` which doesn't allow you to set the unoconv binary path, you can use [unoconv-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unoconv-promise).

Following are sample code with specified unoconv binary location

```
unoconv
  .run({ 
    bin: '/usr/local/bin/unoconv',
    file: "./myppt.pptx",
    output: "./temp.pdf",
    export: "PageRange=1-1"
  })
  .then(filePath => {
    console.log(filePath);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    throw e;
  });
```